# How would you build a realistic Le Palm D'Orbit?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space-constructs

I was watching futurama yesterday and the Le Palm D'Orbit struck me as a fun concept.[image]
How would you go about building a orbital restaurant like the Le Palm? What kinda shape would allow the space needle like shape to have gravity in the dinning room and the apartments, but for my own twist, zero gravity sections for a zero-g dance club and then a loading dock for cargo ships?

Note: Rough dimensions would be .5 mile high (space needle looking bit) and 1 mile long (central disk)

I'd prefer if the dining room could still be facing "up" towards earth with the view of earth being the ceiling for the dining room. If that's not possible screens will do.

Artificial gravity isn't a thing (past centrifugal, linear acceleration, etc)

Comment: centrifugal is the only way to have an 'up', but you could put mirrors to make it appear as though the earth is 'above' the floor

Comment: @Stephan: why bother with mirrors? Cameras and a load of HDTV’s, then you can switch it up to the orbit of... hell, anything! Or blue skies. Or a reniessance style painted ceiling. Just don’t let anyone do maintenance outside while the feeds are live...

Comment: You could, and you could keep the image stabilized to hide the fact that you're spinning in a top. Apparently disorientation is a real problem in space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be my approach :

Grey - outside landing docks for spaceships, *don't rotate*

Orange - Restaurant, rotating, centrifugal forces lead to gravity

Blue - Zero G facilities(dance room etc)

[image: Sketch]

But of course, as Stephan already mentioned, this would require our Palm to rotate sideways around earth(as if it was "rolling" on the atmosphere), so you would have to simulate the nice view to the earth by using displays - or, as Stephan proposed - mirrors.